# PHP/MySQL update a news record in a database problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code that I am trying to use to let a user edit a news record in a form and then when they hit the submit button, it will update the record in a database. The problem is that everything works but the record is not actually updated in the database.

Could someone look at my code and see where a problem could occur?

```
<?php
    $title = "Edit News";
    include("../includes/header.php");
    include("../includes/database.php");
    $done = false;
    $expected = array('newstitle', 'newscontent', 'id');
    if ($_GET && !$_POST) { 
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { 
            $id = $_GET['id']; 
        } 
        else { 
            $id = NULL; 
        } 
        if ($id) { 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id"; 
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error connecting to database..."); 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        } 
        // if form has been submitted, update record 
        if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) { 
            // prepare expected items for insertion into database 
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
                if (in_array($key, $expected)) { 
                    ${$key} = mysql_real_escape_string($value); 
                } 
            } 
            // abandon the process if primary key invalid 
            if (!is_numeric($id)) { 
                die('Invalid request'); 
            }
            // prepare the SQL query 
            $query = "UPDATE news SET title = '$title', content = '$content' WHERE id = $id"; 
            // submit the query 
            $done = mysql_query($query) or die("Error connecting to database..."); 
        }
    }
    // redirect page if $id is invalid 
    if ($done) { 
        header("Location: $ROOT/admin/listnews.php"); 
        exit; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($_GET && !$_POST) {
```

...

```
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) {
```

Won't that ensure the update code never fires?

Answer (score 0):

If you run that UPDATE from the mysql cli with the same data the user sends does it update?

If not check for escaping characters.

Answer (score 0):

Should $content and $title in the line below be $newstitle and $newscontent?

```
// prepare the SQL query 
$query = "UPDATE news SET title = '$newstitle', content = '$newscontent' WHERE id = $id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try and narrow down the problem:

- echo out some debug text just inside the `if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST))`  block to make sure you're actually getting in there. The top of your "if" is `if($_GET && !$_POST)`, so you may need to change this `$_POST` to `$_GET`
- have you tried echoing out `$query` just before the db call? Does it run on the command line mysql interface ok?
- if my reading of your `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` is correct, you'll end up setting variables with the same names as those in `$expected` - (`$newstitle, $newscontent, $id`) - but in your sql reference `$content` and `$title`. They may be the cause of this bug, but something to keep an eye out for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing the HTML source of your form, but I think that the

```
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) {
```

block needs to be moved out of the outer if, since it will never be executed if it's there.

If you don't want to use some sort of testing framework, `print()` is your friend when it comes to debugging your code. Try to find what's executing and what's not; you'll quickly discover which of your assumptions are incorrect, and therefore where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

Take this if statement out of the nested if:

```
 if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) { 
...
}
```

and then add this conditional:

```
 if (count($_POST) && array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) { 
...
}
```

I'm pretty sure that will take care of your problem.